# django-rest-framework-simplejwt validate parameter inside the token

Tags: django, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I use django-rest-framework-simplejwt  to authentification.
In each request I need to check tokens if some variable is valid (if create_time < last change password  i will refuse connection).
Whats the best way to do it in django?

I think the best solution is to create new class with validation, but I have no idea what it should include? I have 3 candidates

```
'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',
'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found:

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':('my_class','rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',)

class my_class(JWTAuthentication):
def authentication(self, request):
validation check